# Converting string like "15:45" into a double like 15.45

Tags: java, string, double

I'm struggling to figure out how to convert a string like "15:45" into a double like 15.45,
I have previously come across methods like `.toString()` and was looking up a similar method to use in order to convert string to double, however there are several issues, I need to figure out how to make `:` be a place where dot `.` is inserted in double.

This is where I would like to use it.

```
if(westOne > (takeOff.firstInQueue().time)) {}
```

At the moment `westOne` is a `double` where as `takeOff.firstInQueue().time` is a string like `"16.15"` I'm assuming I'll need to create my own method to get this working so I can than apply it at the end of it?

Comment: Well, "15:45".replace(":", ".") will do it, but is that really what you want? It looks like a time, not a decimal.

Comment: If you want to store a time as a `double`, you might consider scaling it, so 15:45 would become 15.75, etc.

Comment: @PaulDraper I've got a big number of object where I need to increase time by 5 min, all times are stored as strings, so Instead of going through them one b one, I figured I'll loop through them, convert to doubles ad 0.05 and then get them back to string.

Comment: You know that you can used `"13:00".compareTo("15:45")` if comparison is the reason you want the `double`.

Comment: @PaulDraper it actually is, however once I compare and if statement is true, I'll need to add 5 minutes to westOne, and I assume I'll need to use a numeric type for this.

Comment: Then look at Maroun's answer to see why what you asked for won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply:

```
myDouble = Double.parseDouble(myStr.replace(":", "."));
```

If that's really what you want, this will replace `:` with `.` and the *String* `x:y` will be the *double* `x.y`.

---

**Edit**:

If you want to add 5 minutes to the time, you can add `0.05` to the *double* and convert it back to String, but this is not a good way of doing it because:

- You should take care of cases like `14:55`, adding `0.05` will result `14.6`.
- And cases like `14:45` where adding `0.05` will result `14.5` (No `0` after `5`).

If all what you want is to add `5` minutes to the time, you can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
String myStr = "17:23";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = df.parse(myStr ); 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
myStr = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()); //Now myStr will be 17:28
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this would work;

```
String value;
double value1;
value = String.replaceAll(":",".") // Converts the 15:45 to 15.45
value1 = Double.parseDouble(value) // Converts the 15.45 to a double value.
```

Comment: Not sure if i corrected properly, correct me if i'm wrong.
I think we need a String value into order to use the second one to turn it into a Double, unless you can turn a double into double again ._.

Comment: How this differs from my answer? :)

Comment: For new people, they don't always understand the more advanced methods and also i did not see your post when i saw this.

Comment: That's OK :) +1 for simplifying it.

Comment: Thank you for understanding.
Glad we helped someone :D

Answer (score 0):

```
String timevalue = "15:45";
Double pointvalue = Double.parseDouble(timevalue.replace(':', '.'));
//Not double quote like the previous answer because it takes a char as a parameter and not a string
```